# When to Override writeObject/readObject?

Tags: java, serialization

Seems like a pretty straight forward question but I can't find a direct answer on the google's.

I have a simple IPC channel between two processes over UDP. Each message is wrapped in a header class (e.g. data-driven).

Ex.

```
enum Type 
{ 
 HELLO,
 BYE,
 LISTEN,
}

class Message
{
Type type;
Object data;
}
```

The `Message` is what I am sending to the `ObjectOutputStream writeObject`. This works fine for messages without a `data` payload (e.g. `HELLO` and `BYE`). However the `LISTEN` message sets the `data` attribute to a custom class (with all POD types) and it never seems to reach the other process. When I `readObject` on the other side I get nothing.

So my question is do I need a implement `writeObject` and `readObject` inside my `Message` class and/or inside the `data's` class-type?

**--- Update 1 ---**

Yes both the the `Message` type and underlying `data` type have `implements Serializable` and all eclipse was generate a `serialVersionUID` for me. Is that sufficient? I'm still not seeing the `data` portion of the message.

Comment: class `Message` must implement `Serializable`. This interface is empty, you don't need to override any methods.

Comment: Also check if all inner classes of `Message` are `Serializable` too. Maybe this can help you

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that all object written to `ObjectOutputStream` are `Serializable`.

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) clearly states:

> Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be
>   written to streams.

Make sure that `class Message` implements `Serializable` or [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface.

---

Based on your update, `Object data` is an `Object` and by default, `Object` isn't `Serializable`. You can declare it as `Serializable data`. As mentioned before, *Only Serializable objects can be written to OutputStream*.

Comment: It does. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I've got to be missing some other piece here. Even if I change the `data` to be of type `Foo` (that it is when I assign it), it still doesn't get sent properly.

Comment: it implemented it yea. Kind of confused. But for the time being I added a check that if the Message.type is of type Foo, then serialize Message.data directly which works.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `writeObject` and `readObject` is not a necessary condition for an object to be serializable - they are only meant to customize serialization, not enable it.

Answer (score 0):

By just implementing the Serializable interface an object is ready for serialitzation. However you can override those methods to allow for custom serialitzation. For instance, you might want to Serialize a GregorianCalendar. GregorianCalendar has a huge ammount of data (time zones etc), and you know, for instance, you only use the day, month and hour. Then you can avoid saving everyhing else by making those methods write just that parts.

Comment: indeed you can, but in 99% of cases, it's not done :)  There's also readResolve and writeReplace which are more useful, allowing you to convert to another object which will be serialized in place of the current object (writeReplace) and replace the newly deserialized object with some other object (readResolve).

Comment: Yeah I knew that, but he wasn't asking wether it is the normal procedure or not :)