# readObject method is not being called

Tags: java

I am trying to test the custom serialization but `readObject()` method is not being called.Although I am able to call the writeObject method.
Can we overload the readObject method().

```
    public class Test {

        String pwd1 ;

        public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("//vhub.lmera.ericsson.se//home//xsinkus//WDP//Desktop2k8R2//COMP_DOCS//Test//kusha1.ser");
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            System.out.println("I am being called ");
            SerilizationTest si = (SerilizationTest)ois.readObject();

            System.out.println("After called ");
            System.out.println(si.name);
            System.out.println(si.pwd);
            //si.readObject();
        }

          private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)
                    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
              ois.defaultReadObject();
                     pwd1  = (String) ois.readObject();
                     System.out.println("I am in ");
                  }
    }
```

Comment: is `Test` supposed to be serializable?

Comment: You notice that you call `readObject()` on an instance of `ObjectInputStream` and not on an instance of `Test`?

Comment: @Thomas `ObjectInputStream` uses the private `readObject` method of `Serializable` objects. [Another related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963445/serialization-readobject-writeobject-overides).

Comment: It doesn't look like you are actually calling the method.  And you're not overloading anything, you've just created a method with the same name.

Comment: @SteveSmith This comment is completely wrong - of course not! It can't be overloaded because it's private - [**it is still used**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4119196/7366707) (if the object is `Serializable`.)

Comment: Yup! You can implement you own readObject/writeObject. Check these posts: [Uses of readObject/writeObject in Serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911833/uses-of-readobject-writeobject-in-serialization) and [When to Override writeObject/readObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770120/when-to-override-writeobject-readobject)

Comment: @1blustone you're right. Another question would be how those objects are being written, i.e. if the file actually contains data in the required format.

Comment: Another question: why are you calling `defaultReadObject()` as well as `readObject()` right afterwards? As per JavaDoc `defaultReadObject()` does "read the non-static and non-transient fields of the current class from this stream", i.e. it should read `pwd1` and thus `readObject()` should run into problems. Do you get any exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Your `readObject` method needs to reside inside the class that implements `Serializable`.  This way, only that class *reads objects* in this user defined manner.

Basically, it's not calling your method because it has no idea it exists.